# Negation of Proper Subset

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Is there a specific symbol to denote that a set is NOT a proper subset of another set? (In other words, that an element of the subset is not a member of the set, or that the subset is equal to the set itself).

Comment: It is ugly: $A \not\subsetneq B$

Comment: @MichaelHardy: It seems the symbol isn't rendered correctly on desktop. I typed `\not\subsetneq` and the `\not` slash is probably exactly over the `\subsetneq` slash. On iOS it is rendered correctly.

Comment: anyway: It should look like $\not\hspace{0.05em}\subsetneq$ `\not\hspace{0.05em}\subsetneq`. Still ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A \not \subset B$ means $A$ is not a subset of $B$.  So does $A\not\subseteq B$.

$A\subsetneq B$ means $A$ is a *proper* subset of $B$.

I don't know a single binary relation symbol that means $A$ is not a proper subset of $B$.  One could write $A \not\subset B$ on the theory that $A\subset B$ means $A$ is a proper subset of $B$, but that could easily be misunderstood without some very explicit comments about the meaning.  I tried this code:

```
A \not \subseteq B
```

That doesn't work; it doesn't look like $A\subsetneq B$ with the binary relation symbol $\subsetneq$ crossed out.

Comment: $A \not \subset B$ and $A\not\subseteq B$ might have different meanings, if we use the convention that a slash through the operation indicates 'negate the operation', e.g. $ x \neq y \equiv \neg (x = y ) $. So we might have $A \not \subset B \equiv \neg ( A \subset B )$ and $A \not \subseteq B \equiv \neg ( A \subseteq B )$, thus they are logically different. It seems redundant to give the same meaning for $A \not \subset B$ and $A\not\subseteq B$. Also the problem arises of finding a single binary relation symbol for *$A$ is not a proper subset of $B$* . Who decides these usage conventions.